# Check if app was published by TestFlight

Tags: xamarin.ios, testflight

Is it possible to check in code if the app was started or published by TestFlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you do this at compile time?

```
#if TESTFLIGHT
public const bool IsTestFlightBuild = true;
#else
public const bool IsTestFlightBuild = false;
#endif
```

Then in your project's settings, create a build configuration `TestFlight|iPhone` with `TESTFLIGHT` set.  Only publish to TestFlight with this build configuration.

Comment: First of all thank you;)
But how do I crate a build configuration with TESTFLIGHT as target?