# Detect If Build is Testflight at Runtime

Tags: ios, xcode

In swift, I can easily detect if my build is testflight by doing something like this:

`let isTestFlight = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.path == "sandboxReceipt"`

However, I need to detect if the build is testflight at runtime. I have a Run Script Phase which has this clause:

```
# Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]
then
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
else
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
fi
```

In the first if statement, I need an `&&` operator to detect if the build is not a testflight build. How can I detect if the build is testflight in this script?

Comment: figured, so in other words, to achieve what I want is not possible @matt

Comment: @matt "but something you should not even want" I disagree, I am only doing this for organizing analytics. Ex; when our internal testers are testing the beta, we don't that data to get mixed in with the production analytics. Not sure why you would refer to this as a kiss of death lol

Comment: Ah! Ok that makes sense

Comment: So just use the Other Swift Flags for those builds. Just like you can detect a Debug build at runtime. Basically it’s a feature flag in the build system.

Comment: @grantespo that would be useful. I need to make a script to delete the settings bundle when it's an app store build, and keep the file for test flight builds. Currently I'm able to check if it's release or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if app was published by TestFlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546750/check-if-app-was-published-by-testflight)